# How do I divide the result of this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wmi, wmi-query

So I need to get the CPU temp for my program, and I am using the code below.

So, to get the CPU temp I used this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI",
            "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature instance");
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("CurrentTemperature: {0}", (queryObj["CurrentTemperature"]));
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        Console.Write(e);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I need to add 2732 and divide it by 10 to get the value in celsius, but I can't find the variable to divide?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Temperature is in queryObj["CurrentTemperature"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store queryObj["CurrentTemperature"] in a variable

```
var temp = queryObj["CurrentTemperature"];
```

cast it to an int then do your addition and division.

Answer (score 0):

That's your temperature: `queryObj["CurrentTemperature"]`.

This is of type `object`, so you first need to cast it to `int`, `double` or `float`, depending on the actual type. You can get the type by calling `GetType()` on the object.